# Add item dynamically in listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a linear layout include a list view and a edit text which is below the listview. Then, I put all of them in a scrollview. I want  add item for the listview dynamically. If there is only listview, everything is fine. However, when I add the edit text below the listview, the height of the listview doesn't change although I use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() function. I want when I put item in the listview, the edit text is also pushed down. What can I solve my issue? Thanks

My layout is quite simple like this

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"/>

 <ScrollView
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   </ListView>

   <EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="example"> 

   </EditText>
 </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

UPDATE MY DETAIL DESIGN
[image]

Comment: show your xml file.......

Comment: @Piyush Gupta it's just a simple linearlayout which includes a listview and an edit text below listview

Comment: Relative layout working like drag & drop functionality whether Linear Layout has a fix orientation vertical and horizontal...... you have to give margin , padding and also weight for your xml element.

Comment: @Piyush Gupta I just defined the orientation veritical for linearlayout. Others I set as default. As I mentioned, my layout is simple and works well until I add the edittext below the listview

Comment: so give a weight to both

Comment: @Piyush Gupta I can't use weight because the lauout is scroll. When the list is long, I scroll down and the the edit text is always below the list

Comment: you can add a edittext as a footer to listView

Comment: I've updated my layout. I put the edit text below the listview

Comment: Check out my edit, let me know if I need to explain anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some efforts, I solved my problem by adding the header and footer to the listview without measured the height of the list. 
It made me confused when getting the item but somehow, I got it.

```
ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(
                    android.R.id.list);
            headerView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_dish_step_header, null);
            listView.addHeaderView(headerView);
            TextView mDishName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(
                    R.id.tv_dish_name_in_step);
            mDishName.setText(mGlobal.getDishName());
            footerView = View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_dish_step_footer, null);
            listView.addFooterView(footerView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a relative layout? Then you can add the following to your edit text in xml: android:layout_below="@+id/your_listview_id"

**EDIT**

The adapter

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    List<String> itemList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Context context;

    void addItem(String item){
        itemList.add(item);
    }

    public ListAdapter(Context context){
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return itemList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View list;
        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        list = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        TextView text = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        text.setText(itemList.get(position));

        if (itemList.get(position).toString().trim().equals("edit")){
            // Add a Edit text dynamically
            text.setText("Edit text here");
        }

        return list;
    }

}
```

The onCreate()

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_uga);
    ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    List<String> list_content = new ArrayList<String>();
    listAdapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext());
    list_content.add("1");
    list_content.add("2");
    list_content.add("3");
    list_content.add("4");
    list_content.add("5");
    list_content.add("6");
    list_content.add("7");
    list_content.add("8");
    list_content.add("9");
    list_content.add("10");
    list_content.add("edit");

    list.setAdapter(listAdapter);

    for (String text : list_content){
        listAdapter.addItem(text);
    }

}
```

Comment: No, I haven't tried relative layout. Let me try to replace linearlayout by relative layout. But what's different?

Comment: This will most likely display the edit text below your list view. If you want your edit text to be displayed at the bottom of your list you will need to edit your list adapter. Let me know if the suggestion solved your issue, otherwise you will need some code

Comment: Well, I just need the edit text below the list and when the list is longer, the edittext will be pushed down.Are there any ways to keep my current adapter of the listview because the list and the edittext are different?

Comment: You can just mod your list adapter a bit to display a edit text in the last list row. Im assuming that your are adding a array of items to your list view? As a last record you can just add some text like: editText and then write some code in your list adapter to add a edit text instead of the content. There are a couple of ideas how to do this. Your list view will only scroll through the content added to it, that is why the edit text is visible and not at the end of the list. Make sense?

Comment: If I change to RelativeLayout and set the position of the edit text always below the listview. Will the edit text be pushed down? All of them are put in a scrollview and the layout of height of all of them is wrap content. So, if the listview becomes longer, the edit text will be pushed down and I can scroll down. Right? I haven't tried but that's all my thought

Comment: Nope, you will need to change something in your list adapter to accomplish that, for instance giving your edit text its own row. I am quickly writing something to explain and will add it to a edit soon.

Comment: Take a look of my detail view that I want to have. I just want to refresh only listview, not all

Comment: I took a look. The only way you will be able to display a edit text at the bottom of your list view would be to add your edit text to your list view. Otherwise it will just always be visible below your list view. Did you check the list adapter out? There is a more elegant way of doing this type of thing, I just did that to show where you can add a edit text in the list

Comment: I'll try. However, what happen when I want to add some listview below the listview, not only edit text? I meant some different dynamic listview in a layout

Comment: It would probably be better to start navigation to other activities if you want to display another separate listview. Or add the data to your current listview, owel, that seems like another question

Comment: I finally can add the item for the listview dynamically. I overrided the onDataDetChangd function and calculate the size of the listview. That's all

Comment: Well, accept as answer to so that it can help others? It was a pleasure, and good luck with the rest of it

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't put your listview into the scrollview, listview is scrollable.

2) If you want to fix your edittext below listview and be onscreen all the time, you can get it when compound linearlayout and relativelayout, smth like that:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <RelativeLayout weight='1' height='wrap_content'>
       <YouListView />
   </RelativeLayout>
   <EditText />
</LineadLayout>
```

In this case you RelativeLayout will fill all possible area excluding edittext's area.

3) If you want this edittext to be a part of listview use footer in listview instead.

4) You can use different layouts for each row in list but in this case you have to manage this views more accurate to avoid performance issues.

Comment: No, I want it below the listview as the above photo. When the list becomes longer, the edit text will be pushed down and I need to scroll down to see the edit text. That's what I want

Comment: Listview has to be scrolled like in web frame? For example when i touch imageview i scroll the whole scrollview and when I scroll listview, i scroll only listview even it's not fully on screen? Like in web when you scroll over the page and then focus your mouse on long fixed size text area?

Comment: yes, it's similar to web view. Anyway, I solved my issue but now I have another problem that when I want to drag to sort the item in the listview, it's not possible. Any suggestion?

Comment: I checked it but what happen when I need to add a lot of things, not only edittext? Can you give me more detail instructions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="vertical"/>

   <ListView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1">
   </ListView>

   <EditText
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="example"> 

   </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Mistakes you did in your code

1) Including Listview inside Scrollview is very bad practice.

2) When you deal with LinearLayout wight attribute plays the keyrole. And you have not used that attribute

If this solution doesn't work provide me dummy screen shot of the layout which you want to design. I will help you.

Comment: @lolyoshi : I would suggest not to use ListView. But you can have LinerLayout instead and create views in that container dynamically. And put that Linear Layout In ScrollView. I hope you got what I am trying to convey.

Comment: I must use list view because that's the requirement :(

Answer (score -2):

I finally solved my problem by calculate the size of the listview in the onDataSetChanged function

```
ListAdapter mAdapter = listView.getAdapter();

    int totalHeight = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < mAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        View mView = mAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);

        mView.measure(
                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),

                MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));

        totalHeight += mView.getMeasuredHeight();
        Log.w("HEIGHT" + i, String.valueOf(totalHeight));

    }

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = totalHeight
            + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (mAdapter.getCount() - 1));
    listView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: This method is very performance consuming and you lost all features that listview had given to you. You can have 500+ items in listview and for all of this item you will build a view. Feature of listview is to store only N+2 views (N - number of views that fit screen). If you have to you can count measures only for visible views.

Comment: @dilix Maybe but do you have any better solutions?